# Select Finder windows move to different workspaces without reason

Tags: finder

This question is NOT a duplicate of any of these:

- [VLC shows up in all desktops](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/219950/54495)
- [Preview assigned on all desktop on BigSur](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/412010/preview-assigned-on-all-desktop-on-bigsur)
- [Notes appearing on all sets in stage manager](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/451113/notes-appearing-on-all-sets-in-stage-manager)
- [Mail appears in every desktop](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/439200/mail-appears-in-every-desktop)

I think it MIGHT be considered a clarification of this closed question, which seems to be an attempt to ask this question but not provide enough information:

- [Prevent finder window from switching between spaces when using Mission Control](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/451353/prevent-finder-window-from-switching-between-spaces-when-using-mission-control)

**Background:**
I have multiple workspaces on my Mac. I uses windows in different workspaces as part of my workflow. For instance, my games I play most frequently are in a window that I leave in one workspace at the end of all my spaces. I have one screen that I have my downloads folder (with multiple tabs in it) open along with some apps. I do 3D design and printing, so I have Blender in one workspace, a window open to my 3D files in the next, and, after that, my slicer program is open in the next space. So I put my windows in specific spaces for my workflow.

**Main Issue:**
The Finder windows mover around, without me moving them, without me having it set so Finder windows always show up in one workspace. For instance, I play a game in WS9 (WorkSpace 9), close it, and Finder now becomes the active app. I press Command-5 to move to my browsers in WS5 and the games window moves - and switches to a different tab than the one I was using.

Again, I have to stress, that I do NOT have Finder windows assigned to any specific workspace, nor do I have them set to follow me. When I reboot, I set up my workspace to be sure certain Finder windows, with specific tabs open in them, are in specific workspaces. Until I upgraded to Ventura, they stayed where I put them, but once I started using my new Mac Mini (over a year ago), this started happening. Windows are not assigned to "All Desktops" or to any specific desktop. They are not assigned at all.

I am using one display and my spaces are not automatically re-arranged.

**More examples:**
I'm on WS5 and move to WS4 to work in the Notes app. My game window, on WS9, where I haven't been, suddenly appears on WS4. I go to Mission Control and move that window back to WS9. Then I have to move from WS4 to WS5, read something in my browser, and go back to WS4 and the same Finder window, with my games, AGAIN appears on WS4. This keeps happening. I move it from WS4 to WS9 with Mission Control, so I don't go back to WS9. It doesn't show up when I leave WS4 to go to 5 again, but always shows when I go back to WS4.

Often I'm working in a simple text editor and with iTerm2 for programming. I take a break and go from WS6 (with the text editor and iTerm2 open) to WS9 and play a game for 2 minutes, then close it. Then I use Command-6 and the game window goes to WS6 with me. I have to move it back to WS9.

This is unpredictable. For instance, just now, I went from WS5 to WS9, clicked on the annoying and moving games window and went back to WS5. Nothing. Went to WS4 and it still did not follow. It *seems* like this happens to some windows and not others. Also, I have had times where I leave my Mac on for weeks at a time and find after a while it stops happening. I don't know what I do that stops it, but sometimes it stops.

I've seen this issue discussed on Apple's website, but there are no conclusions. People claim to have reported it as a bug, but nothing's happened with it.

I'd like to find out what's going on and stop it. (Heck, if I can stop it, I don't care as much about what's going on.)